# How can I get the parent object in Django Rest Framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

Now in my `TrackSerializer` I want to get the name of album.

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('album__name')
```

It's not working.

I don't want to declare AlbumSerializer for that. Is there any way to do that without declaring a new serializer?

Comment: You can just set `depth=1` on your TrackSerializer. This will automatically serialize the parent models

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass an iterable to the `fields` attribute in `Meta`? You are passing a string because you didn't put a comma after `'album__name'` in your serializer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this by creating a field on your `TrackSerializer` that [has a custom `source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) that retrieves the album name.

> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as URLField('get_absolute_url'), or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as EmailField(source='user.email').

So in your case, the field `album_name` would need to be added with the custom `source` set

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source="album.name")

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ("album_name", )
```

This will include the album name in the output under the key `album_name`.

Comment: can send the link for rest docs where it says that we can access peoperties with `album.name` syntax , i could not find it

Comment: "The name of the attribute ... or may use dotted notation to traverse attributes, such as EmailField(source='user.email')." Directly from the link I included, under the `source` argument

Comment: sorry i didnt saw that

Answer (score 9):

To include the parent relation you only need to include its serializer and include it in the fields list.

```
Class TrackSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumSerializer()

    class Meta:
         model = Track
         fields = ('name', 'year', 'album',)
```

Comment: what if i want to do the opposite get the track in the album?

Comment: This is useful as long as you are using TrackSerializer to list tracks along with album object. But when you want to create a track object, you pass the track params and album id, it expects a complete album object. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to create a browseable api for one of my Django 2.0 projects, one that would allow a api user to drill down with hyperlinks into the children and then back again, or even start with a child and find the parent or grandparent through a hyperlinks. Also, instead of using the `pk` number, I wanted to use a slug field for finding the relations.

I could not find any complete solution for what I wanted to do, just bits and pieces, but I was finally able to putting a working api together. I hope that someone will find the solution that, extends the 'Album - Track' example, useful.

I apologise for all the code, but by copying and pasting you should be able to put together a working example.

This is this content in my `models.py` file. Please note the "related_name" parameter in the ForeignKey-fields. It is really important to make the whole setup work.

```
#models.py
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=False)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=False, 
                    on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, 
                    default=1, related_name='albums')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=False)

class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=False, 
                     on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1, 
                     related_name='artist_tracks')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, blank=True, null=True,  
                     on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                     related_name='album_tracks')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

Below is `serializers.py`. This is where I struggled the most with the error `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "artist-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the 'lookup_field' attribute on this field.` Resolving the children was quote easy and is facilitated by the model. The key to getting the url for the parents lie in the `queryset` parameter of the `HyperlinkRelatedField` serializer along with `lookup_field= 'slug'`. Below is my serializer classes.

```
#serializers.py
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    albums = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='album-detail',
        lookup_field='slug')
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'slug', 'albums') #, 'artist_tracks'
        lookup_field = 'slug',
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Artist.objects.all(),
        lookup_field='slug',
        view_name='artist-detail'
    )
    album_tracks = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='track-detail'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'artist', 'album_tracks')
        lookup_field = 'slug',
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }

class TrackSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    artist = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Artist.objects.all(),
        lookup_field='slug',
        view_name='artist-detail'
    )
    album = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        queryset=Album.objects.all(),
        lookup_field='slug',
        view_name='album-detail'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'artist', 'album')
```

Here the content of my `urls.py`.

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('artist/', ArtistList.as_view(), name='artist-list'),
    path('artist/<slug:slug>/', ArtistDetail.as_view(), name='artist-detail'),
    path('album/', AlbumList.as_view(), name='album_list'),
    path('album/<slug:slug>/', AlbumDetail.as_view(), name='album-detail'),
    path('track/', TrackList.as_view(), name='track-list'),
    path('track/<int:pk>/', TrackDetail.as_view(), name='track-detail'),
]
```

Next `views.py`. Please note the `lookup_field='slug'` in the `...Detail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):` classes.

```
class ArtistList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

class ArtistDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

class AlbumList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

class AlbumDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

class TrackList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Track.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer

class TrackDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Track.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackSerializer
```

Using this approach I was able to product the following JSON for tracks from where one can find both the related artist and album:

```
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/track/4/",
"name": "Lifeline",
"artist": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/artist/neal-morse/",
"album": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/album/lifeline/"
}
```

And for the albums I am able to generate JSON that looks like below, which allows one to find the artist and all the tracks of the album.

```
{
"url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/album/lifeline/",
"name": "Lifeline",
"artist": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/artist/neal-morse/",
"album_tracks": [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/track/4/",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/track/5/",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/track/6/"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (making use of Python dynamism):

```
def create_serializer(target_class, fields):
    class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = target_class
            fields = fields

    return ModelSerializer
```

So, a Track serializer can be created using this approach:

```
TrackSerializer = create_serializer(Track, ('album__name',))
```

Also, be careful of **('album__name')**, which is a parenthesized string expression and not a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) as you probably intended. To declare it as a tuple, add a comma after it, like this:

```
fields = ('album__name',)
```

Comment: album__name is not working as field name. This what i was asking in my question. you have solved the way to make serilizer factory but original problem still remian that i can't traverse album__name in serilaizer

Answer (score -4):

Looks like you need You need [Serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

It also appears a question very similar to this has been asked already: [django rest framework view does'nt show related table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763588/django-rest-framework-view-doesnt-show-related-table-data)

Comment: I think  the example give on docs page is Albums have tracks with stringrelatedField i want Track to get ALbum . ther everse of what is shown in docs